# Unable to compile GWT Cell Showcase examples

Tags: gwt, uibinder

I have been trying to understand gwt Widgets showcase at the below link:

http://gwt.google.com/samples/Showcase/Showcase.html#!CwCellList

I am not able to compile the code, this code is using UiBinder but they are not binding it to template which gives me error "Template file ContactInfoForm.ui.xml is missing (expected at com/tracker/client/view)"

any idea how to get this sample running, gwt sample directory (get downloaded with gwt) is not having the part of examples...

Thanks in Advance...

Comment: i was not having the gwt 2.xx , i am downloading it.... may be that solves some of the issues....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code given at the website is not complete but once we download the gwt 2.1..RC1 it comes with the sample codes.

I am able to compile and run the samples.